# Show app contacts in phone contact list

Tags: java, android

Okay - I have created a app, where I have a list of employees with name, phonenumber, address and so on.
Each users is either a Employee, client etc.

I want this to be visible in my contact list. But im not sure how to do this - the problem is properly that I dont know what I should search after. I have tried to search after Contact provider, but im not sure if this is correct.

If we look at this link, https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-set-up-your-contact-list. Here I want this to show my app, and where you can select which groups to show - Employee, Client, etc.

My question is, where do I find the information to get started with this?

Comment: What are you asking? Do you want us to write your program?

Comment: Ofcause not - I just need a direction where to find the correct information. Right now, Im not sure where to look to get started with this. Sorry not to be clear about this.